# Issue with using arrays in java?

Tags: java

So, I have a class `Square` and I am trying to use an array for it `board`. Here is my code:

```
public class Square{
   public int pcolor;
   public int contains;
   public int xPos;
   public int yPos;
   Square(int xp,int yp,int pc,int cont){
       xPos=xp;
       yPos=yp;
       contains=cont;
       pcolor=pc;
   }
};
Square[] board = new Square[64];
board[0].xPos=0;
```

This gives me `unexpected token: [` on `board[0].xpos=0;`. Can anyone help me resolve this?

---

EDIT:

OK, I moved `board[0].xpos=0;` inside a method; now it gives me NullPointerException. What do I do?

Comment: Please post some more code. This looks like a syntax error.

Comment: The error is on a different line, please post more of your code.

Comment: sorry, when i edited it i deleted it :X

Comment: This is not the full code then. Anyone who will compile this will get a compile-time error that the statements on the bottom are unexpected (they need to be in a method in the same or different class. And then get a run-time null pointer exception that you are not setting each array value to a new Square object.

Comment: For your edit initialize every value to a new object. board[0] = new Square(num, num, num, num);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to make a statement not inside a method or a static scope.

The statement `board[0].xPos = 0;` should [probably] be inside a method.

You also seem to have a redundant `};`

This code compiles just fine:

```
public class Square{
    public int pcolor;
    public int contains;
    public int xPos;
    public int yPos;
    Square(int xp,int yp,int pc,int cont){
        xPos=xp;
        yPos=yp;
        contains=cont;
        pcolor=pc;
    }
    Square[] board = new Square[64];
}
```

To initialize [and access] elements in `board` - you will have to do it in a method or in the constructor.

Comment: Why is Square[] board inside of class Square

Comment: @user1188752: I have no idea what you are actually trying to do. It is just a sample of a code that is compiling. Without more information on what you are trying to achieve - I could only guess.

Comment: Chess game in Processing - Square is one square on the board

Comment: @user1188752 Then `Square[] board` should probably be inside a `Game` class or something indeed. Now that you have solved the compilation error - note that `Square[] board = new Square[64];` does not create `Square`s. It only create the array, holding `null`s. You will need to initialize `board[i] = new Square(...);` for each `i`.

Comment: @user1188752: Try to "play with it", and see if you can figure it out. If not - avoid editting this question with new issues - you should post a new question - describing the new situation and the new problem. I am sure someone will answer you pretty quickly...

Comment: I fixed it with your previous post

Comment: @amit I would like to up vote you, but i don't have enough rep :P

Comment: @user1188752: As an asker you can accept [as you had] which is just as good! I am glad I could help you, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do this correctly you will get `NullPointerException` because you didn't create any object yet. My guess is you did some syntax error.

Comment: What do you mean, "you didn't create any object yet"?

Comment: @amit I am thinking he might be using an IDE which would pre-process the syntax since he might have put the statements outside of a method.

Comment: @skynorth: I don't think so, I think that the fact that the statements are not in a method - caused the compilation error - as expected.

Comment: @amit the fact that he got unexpected token compilation error tells me that he is using a custom IDE (and not even real Java, see his above comment). The Java compiler would never give that kind of compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

All the `Square`s in `board` are `null` and you're trying to access a field of a null Object...

You can initialize the array with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    board[i] = new Square(...something_here...);
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you should consider using a `Square[][]`!